# Reference request: an elementary result on characters of finite abelian groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, abelian-groups, characters

The referee of a paper I submitted to a journal asked me to include a reference of the following elementary result on characters of finite abelian groups:

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group of order $N$ and let
$\hat A$ be its dual group. Let $a\in A$ have order $h$. Then 
$$\prod_{\chi\in\hat A}(1-\chi(a)T)=(1-T^h)^{N/h}.$$

I don't want to include a proof because one of the good things about this paper (I hope not the only one) is that is short.

I have searched in books about abelian groups, finite groups, representations, and number theory, but I could not find it. As usual, the only place I could find it is in one of the (magnificent) "blurbs" by Keith Conrad.

Does anyone knows a book where I can actually find this result?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks, I didn't knew that general result. The thing is that the article is on analytic number theory and only uses this result in a very elementary way. But, if I don't find any reference I will consider what you say. Thanks again.

Comment: Another approach:  since taking character groups is exact for (I think arbitrary, but certainly for) finitely generated Abelian groups, the left-hand side is $\bigl(\prod_{\chi \in \widehat{\langle a\rangle}} (1 - \chi(a)T)\bigr)^{[A \mathbin: \langle a\rangle]}$, which is easily seen to be as stated.

Comment: I think I first saw this in Lang's book on cyclotomic fields, perhaps in the early sections where he uses characters with Jacobi sums. Have you looked there or in Narkiewicz's massive tome on algebraic number theory?  Anyway, I wonder if you really need to cite the literature since a proof is short. Since $a$ has order $h$, the mapping $\widehat{A} \rightarrow \mu_h$ by $\chi \mapsto \chi(a)$ is a surjective homomorphism, so each $h$th root of unity is a value $|\widehat{A}|/h = |A|/h = N/h$ times. Thus the product is $\prod_{z^h=1} (1-zT)^{N/h} = (1 - T^h)^{N/h}$, QED.

Comment: For $A=(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, this appears explicitly in Serre's Course in Arithmetic (Chapter VI, Lemma 6).

Comment: Why not cite that blurb then?

Comment: @KConrad, isn't [your proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312576/reference-request-an-elementary-result-on-characters-of-finite-abelian-groups#comment779657_312576) the same as [mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312576/reference-request-an-elementary-result-on-characters-of-finite-abelian-groups#comment779642_312576)?

Comment: This only needs a word. It is merely a restatement of the fact, found in almost every representation theory text, that ${\rm Res}_{A}^{\langle a \rangle}(\rho_{A})=[A:\langle a\rangle]\rho_{\langle a \rangle}$, where $\rho_{B}$ denotes the regular representation of the group $B$ (applied in the case that $A$ is Abelian),

Comment: @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე perhaps the difficulty with your suggestion (hence the OP's question) is that the referee wants an officially published reference. More than once I have gotten emails from people in the OP's situation for a similar reason.

Comment: @LSpice yes, indeed it is.  I had not read your argument closely before posting my reply.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, how did your comment jump forward 6 hours in time?

Comment: @LSpice: I deleted the previous version ( because I could not edit it) to clarify that the case $A$ Abelian is the one needed for this question.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think it's complicated, since many academics do not trust non-published texts, perhaps without knowing that these are sometimes much better than published ones, as is the case of KConrad writings.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I did not found it in Lang's Cyclotomic Fields. I will look in Narkiewicz. If I not find it, I'll write the short argument by LSpice and KConrad

Answer (score 3):

1. This is essentially proved in Rosen's "Number Theory in Function Fields", page 109, Lemma 8.14.

[image]

2. This is also proved in Lang's "Algebraic Number Theory" (2nd edition), page 230. It is the equation with (*) in its beginning. The context is abelian extensions, so some of the notation make it seem number-theoretic, but the argument is general. [image]

Comment: If the aim is to have something to cite, then it seems that explaining why Lang's argument is actually about arbitrary Abelian groups (and specialises to the desired result) might take just as long as sketching out the very short proof.

Comment: Your citation to Rosen is not to a result directly about characters of general finite abelian groups (it is about a product of terms $1 - z^ku$ for $n$th roots of unity $z$ and varying $k$, with no characters visible), so I don't think it fits what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you very much, but as @LSpice says I wanted something to cite. I think I will have to prove this in the paper.